# Convert string to array of objects angular 4

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, object

I have this api response :

```
{
   "status": "success",
   "code": 0,
   "message": "version list",
   "payload" : "[{\"code\":\"AB\",\"short\":\"AB\",\"name\":\"Alberta\",\"country\":\"CA\"},{\"code\":\"BC\",\"short\":\"BC\",\"name\":\"British Columbia\",\"country\":\"CA\"}]"

}
```

I am trying to get the name of different object of payload .
 Payload here , is returned as string .

So when I try to get the name of object it doesn't work !

```
getAllPayload() {
  this.myService.getpayload().subscribe(
     data => {
        this.values= data;
     }
   );
}
```

and

```
<select class="form-control">                     
   <option *ngFor="let value of values.payload" >
      {{value.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

And when I try to parse the object by JSON.parse , it doesn't work

What must I do to parse the payload and get the different names ?

Comment: `this.values = JSON.parse(data.payload)`. then `let value of values`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca no , this is not the actual response , when I have put the response in the question I have removed some data , so I have escaped a quote .. I updated the question by a valid response ..

Comment: @G.Ab noted and removed comment

Answer (score 0):

You have unescaped quotes in your String. Once those are escaped, than:

[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```js
var res = {
"payload" : "[{\"code\":\"AB\",\"short\":\"AB\",\"name\":\"Alberta\",\"country\":\"CA\"},{\"code\":\"BC\",\"short\":\"BC\",\"name\":\"British Columbia\",\"country\":\"CA\"}]"
};
  
var payloadArray = JSON.parse(res.payload);
console.log( payloadArray )
console.log( Array.isArray(payloadArray) ) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like :

```
getAllPayload() {
this.myService.getpayload().subscribe(
    data => {
    this.values= JSON.parse(data.payload) // this line converts the payload string to array.

    ;
  }
 );
```

then in template

```
<option *ngFor="let value of values" >
     {{value.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

Hope you get the solution.